# Supervisor to run command after another command has exited?

Tags: 16.04, supervisor

Is it possible for a command to wait until another command has exited?

```
[program:letsencrypt-start]
command=/srv/letsencrypt.sh
priority=1
autostart=true
autorestart=false
stderr_logfile=/var/log/letsencrypt-start.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/letsencrypt-start.out.log

[program:haproxy]
command=haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
priority=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/haproxy.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/haproxy.out.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1GB
redirect_stderr=true
```

I'd like `haproxy` to start after `letsencrypt-start` has the status `EXITED`.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide info on 1) what configuration file this is (what path, what program), 2) whether this is part of a boot sequence or some arbitrary point, 3) what version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @taifwa People who knows supervisor knows by looking at what I've presented. 2) People who know what supervisor is already knows this. 3) Look at the tags.

Comment: My bad. Thought you were using generic terms.

Comment: That being said, my interest is piqued, I could have used this some time ago myself. Looks like you're wanting to set your `haproxy` program to *not* start automatically ; and implement an event listener script to listen for `PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED,PROCESS_STATE_EXITED` that simply runs `supervisorctl start haproxy` if it detects `processname:letsencrypt-start`